# Dimensions.get('window') errors when I try to run react native examples in windows

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to setup windows react native development enviroment and learn the 
examples from react native folders.

the example apk can be installed on my android virtual machine.

but when I click on it, it will pop up with red screen, like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPnfo.jpg

and my packager console error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (native)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
{ Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:715:26)
    at Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at Socket.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:480:10)
    at Socket.end (net.js:431:31)
```

I try to follow and debug on chrome and found:

```
return Dimensions.get('window').scale;
```

got errors like:

```
Uncaught Error: No dimension set for key window
    at invariant (http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:2504:15)
    at Function.get (http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17698:7)
    at eval (eval at evaluate (:85:21), <anonymous>:1:12)
    at Function.get (http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17620:7)
    at Function.roundToNearestPixel (http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17635:30)
    at http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:17557:32
    at loadModuleImplementation (http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:109:5)
    at guardedLoadModule (http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:70:12)
    at _require (http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:54:60)
    at http://localhost:8081/Examples/UIExplorer/js/UIExplorerApp.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:18886:18
```

my react-native version:
"react": "15.4.2",
"react-native": "0.42.3"

my AVD settings is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo1Zn.jpg

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you and Best Regards.

Comment: Can you get anything to render, or is it some functionality specific to this application? Are you saying the app initially renders, but when you try to interact with it you get an error?

Comment: @Adam, Thank for your reply. it happened when I just clicked the App icon on the emulator, no interaction. but I can run the AwesomeProject.

Comment: Are you going to answer my questions?

Comment: Sorry for my slow net speed, the error happened when I opened the UIExplorer example, I did nothing...

Comment: If you are downloading dependencies with HTTPS, this post might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255948/window-react-native-android-development-issue-java-lang-nullpointerexception?rq=1

Otherwise, you might want to reinstall everything, you are probably missing dependencies.

Comment: Thank for your reply,  I try the link you provided,it didnot work, and about dependencies, I can run AwesomeProject by react-native init, but why I failed at examples?

Comment: You would have to post the code to the example you are trying to run so I could look at it. I would guess the examples rely on an older version of react-native. You probably need updated examples, or other revert to an older version of react native.

Comment: @kingkong2015 did you solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using `react-native-router-flux` guys?